# URL to inherit protocol

Tags: html

I read somewhere that there's a trick you can use when linking images, that if you did `://domain.com/images/s.gif` it would inherit the protocol that's currently being used, whether it be `https` or `http`.  This isn't working and I can't remember where I read it, I think [css-tricks.com](http://www.css-tricks.com), am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Drop the `:`. The syntax for [protocol-relative URLs](http://blog.httpwatch.com/2010/02/10/using-protocol-relative-urls-to-switch-between-http-and-https/) is

```
//domain.com/images/s.gif
```